# OSM works on my iPhone but doesn't work at another

Tags: ios, objective-c, openstreetmap

I run OpenStreetMap in my app:

```
NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
MKTileOverlay *overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
[self.mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

It works perfect in my iPhone with iOS 8.3, and customer before update iOS til 9.0 didn't say anything. But now, customer says hi has only grid instead map. Hi has iOS 9 now.
What changed? What should i add in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP, by default, is not supported in iOS 9, so your `initWithURLTemplate` call is failing. When the MKTileOverlay goes online to fetch a tile, it can't do it. Thus, no map appears.

Comment: You don't want to do _any_ research about this? This is a _huge_ change in iOS 9; don't you think that if you want to support you app, it is _your_ job to find out about it?

Comment: You are right matt. Thank you for direction! Thank you for help! :)